# Selecting multiple substrings from a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am a newbie here and I have a php array of some strings, such as {"VAL1","VAL2", "VAL3", "VAL4"} and I have a larger string (normally a text file). The text file contains the elements of the arrays at different positions and some or all may be repeating more than one. Each of of the elements of the array that are contained in the text file are immediately followed by a time of occurence, for example, **"VAL1 0900UTC and other text information"**.The problem now is that I want to find the occurrence(s) of all of the elements of the array in the text file and the time value following the element.
Please note that some of the elements may occur more than once at different positions with different time value in the textfile.
Already, I can load the textfile and get all of the elements.:

```php
    $mytextfile = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(file_get_contents($textpath."/". $textfile)));

    $substr = array("REALTK","BGPTK", "SUDTK", "BECTK");  
    $bigstring = "REALTK 1000UTC 16/14 1011 BGPTK 1030UTC 10/12 992 REALTK 1145UTC 00/14 2222 SUDTK 1412UTC 11/06 1011 REALTK 1600UTC 16/14 1015 ...";

    //I created variables to hold all element occuring to false  
    $is_val1 = false; $is_val2 = false;$is_val3 = false; $is_val4 = false;

    //I created variables to count how many of each substring exist in the string  
       $numofval1=$numofval2=$numofval3=$numofval4=0;  

         if(strpos($bigstring, $substr[0]) !== false) {  
            $is_val1 = true;  
         //if exist, count how many times  
        $numofval1 =  substr_count(strtoupper($bigstring),$substr[0]);
         } e.t.c
```

I have been able to get the occurrence of each of the array elements in the big string
I have been able to detect if any of the array elements occur more than once in big string and number of times it does.
But I have not being able to get them in the sequence they occur with their position in the textfile string and the time value after each element.

```
$mytextfile = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strtoupper(file_get_contents($textpath."/". $textfile)));  

$substr = array("REALTK","BGPTK", "SUDTK", "BECTK");
```

//this is a sample content of the textfile
    $bigstring = "REALTK 1000UTC 16/14 1011 BGPTK 1030UTC 10/12 992 REALTK 1145UTC 00/14 2222 SUDTK 1412UTC 11/06 1011 REALTK 1600UTC 16/14 1015 ...";

```
//I created variables to hold all element occuring to false  
$is_realtk = false; $is_bgptk = false;$is_sudtk = false; $is_bectk = false;  

//I created variables to count how many of each of the element exist in the text file string    
   $numofrealtk=$numofbgptk=$numofsudtk=$numofbectk=0;  

     if(strpos($bigstring, $substr[0]) !== false) {  
        $is_realtk = true;  
     //if exist, count how many times  
    $numofrealtk =  substr_count(strtoupper($bigstring),$substr[0]);
     } e.t.c
```

What I need is to get the Elements of the array in the order in which they occur in the text file with their position and time value

```
REALTK POSITION1 1000UTC
BGPTK POSITION5 1030UTC  
REALTK POSITION8 1145UTC  
SUDTK POSITION13 1412UTC  
REALTK POSITION17 1600UTC
```

I also want to store the element => timevalue as associative array.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I don’t see how your expected output is supposed to match your input data. How do you count the “position”? If VAL1 is pos 1 and VAL4 is pos 2, should VAL2 not be _4_ instead of 5? And why is VAL1 in there only once, did you not say you wanted _all_ occurrences?

Comment: If $bigstring's elements are always seperated by a whitespace, you can just explode your bigstring and do a foreach on the resulting array.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. You could do a onedimensional array with positions as keys instead of "val" by the way.

Comment: `$val_arr` should replace `$substr` i suppose, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in your $bigstring are always divided by a whitespace, you can explode:

```
$val_arr = array( "REALTK" => array(), "BGPTK" => array(), "SUDTK" => array(), "BECTK" => array();
$bigstring_arr = explode( " ", $bigstring);
foreach( $bigstring_arr as $key => $part ){
    if( in_array( $part, $substr ) ){
        $val_arr[$part][] = array( "position" => $key+1, "time" => $bigstring_arr[$key+1] );
    }
}
```

If it's not you can also explode directly on each element of Val1, Val2... . The code gets a bit more complicated then. But it would work as well if you created a new array in the form of "CountOfAllCharsInBigstringBeforeOccurence" => "KeyOfValInSubstr". From that you can derive your ordering with the vals.

Edit:
I edited the code based on your comment. Please note that it is not possible to have an array that has the same key multiple times which is why the solution here will have multiple dimensions.

Comment: this works perfectly for me but I will like to pass the values to an associative array like $part => $pos as key => value so that i can access it individually later on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet for you, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$substr = array("VAL1","VAL2", "VAL3", "VAL4");
$bigstring = "OTHERS VAL1 VAL4 VAL1 OTHERS OTHERS VAL2 OTHERS";
// considering space to explode words and having numbers in it
$temp = array_unique(str_word_count($bigstring, 1,"0..9"));
// sorting generated array and keeping index of value
asort($temp);
// matching records from array
$temp = array_intersect($temp,$substr);
// showing all the data you want 
array_walk($temp,function($item,$k){
    echo $item.' POSITION '.$k."\n"; // replace \n with <br/> if web
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f0aeff0296f063048516e9e0bd4dced1143bdde).

Comment: Thank you for this, I found it useful for other things i was trying to do elsewhere but in this case, i don't want to sort and I want all instances of the $substr array to appear. Your solution is not repeating repeated element in the big string